# execute pair of tasks in Parallel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, task-parallel-library

Having two tasks that execute On/Off, I would like to create list of these (pairs) and execute them in Parallel. Meaning: **each Task encapsulates TaskA and TaskB - and TaskB always waits for TaskA to finish first**. So I should end up with Parallel execution of "set" of TaskA/TaskB

> Task = {TaskA, TaskB} , {TaskA, TaskB}, {TaskA, TaskB}
>   : execute those 3 Sets of tasks in Parallel

```
    private static async Task TaskA()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("ended TaskA");
    }

    private static async Task TaskB()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("ended TaskB");
    }

    static void StartTask()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            TaskA().Wait();
            TaskB().Wait();
        });
    }
```

Main:

```
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        int taskCount = 3;

        for (var i = 0; i < taskCount; i++)
        {
            var task = new Task(StartTask);
            tasks.Add(task);
        }

        Parallel.ForEach(tasks, task => task.Start());
```

Currently I'm getting this:

```
ended TaskA
ended TaskA
ended TaskA
ended TaskB
ended TaskB
ended TaskB
```

I believe the output should be:

```
ended TaskA
ended TaskB
ended TaskA
ended TaskB
// etc..
```

Also, tried this, but still same issue:

```
static void StartTask()
{
    Task task = TaskA().ContinueWith(x => TaskB().Wait(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
}
```

**Edit 1:**

```
    Parallel.For(1, taskCount, (i, state) =>
    {
        TaskA().ContinueWith(x => TaskB().Wait(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
    });
```

Comment: Why not just run taskb from the end of taska?

Comment: I though that's what I was doing

Comment: private static async Task TaskA()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("ended TaskA");TaskB();
    }

Comment: I can not modify TaskA or TaskB. TaskA has to finish before TaskB starts

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=c-sharp+synchronize+threads&ie=&oe=#q=c-sharp+synchronize+tasks and in particular: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2010/06/18/parallel-programming-task-schedulers-and-synchronization-context/

Comment: Are `TaskA` and `TaskB` CPU-Intensive operations? Or are they mostly IO operations?

Comment: TaskA and TaskB Read/Write to ConcurrentDictionary, and they have to be executed in order TaskA => once finished => TaskB

Comment: But the way, the current *output* does not have an issue. Because you run the sets in parallel, A1 ,A2, A3 start in parallel, When A1 finishes, A2 and A3 most probably finish too at the same time, then you see B1,B2, and B3 start in parallel.

Comment: so this is correct? Please see Edit1. I think this makes more sense.Am I correct?

Comment: I don't understand, you're asking for each pair to execute in parallel and the output shows that's what is happening. If you really want the output you say you want, which tasks should execute in parallel?

Comment: @svick - initially i though it would be Set1 ended {a/b}, then Set2 {a/b}...but i see what you're saying. there's no way of knowing

Comment: @BobSwanson, although the output is probably correct. I see some issues with your code. First, `TaskA` and `TaskB` shouldn't be `async` because there is nothing asynchronous about dealing with the `ConcurrentDictionary` class. Second, you shouldn't use the `Start` method of the `Task` class, you should use `Task.Run` to create tasks that are already running.

Comment: I think Edit1 code makes more sense. Am i right?. Edit1 code- run TaskA to completion, then run TaskB to completion. Perform this action (taskCount) number of times. Correct? Another thing, I've added Task.WaitAll(); under Parallel line but it continues to a breakpoint after it, shouldn't it wait to finish running all tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I believe the output should be: ...

No, that's not what "parallel" means. If you're going to start three pairs, then I would expect the output you're already seeing.

That said, there's a few things in the code that don't make sense. First off, distinguish between "parallel" (multiple threads) and "concurrent" (doing multiple things at the same time). It looks like your tasks are naturally asynchronous, so let's rewrite things using asynchronous programming instead of threading:

- Replace `Wait` with `await`.
- Get rid of the `Task.Run`.

It's easier to just compose `TaskA` and `TaskB` into a new "pair task":

```
static async Task PairTaskAsync()
{
  await TaskA();
  await TaskB();
}
```

Now you just want to run 3 of these "pair tasks" concurrently. The old code is using the task constructor and then parallelizes *starting* the tasks - which is pretty much completely wrong, even if we *wanted* to do parallelism. Which we don't; we want asynchronous concurrency.

Asynchronous concurrency is usually achieved with `Task.WhenAll`:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
int taskCount = 3;

for (var i = 0; i < taskCount; i++)
  tasks.Add(PairTaskAsync());

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

or, for maximum succinctness:

```
await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(_ => PairTaskAsync()));
```

Comment: Stephen, can you please add comments to your code to make it clearer?. When PairTaskAsync start? when you add? or at await line?

Comment: Also, where can I put a stopwatch? to know how long TaskA and TaskB in a single pair took to finish?

Comment: Is there book that would explain async/concurrency/parallelism in easy to understand, concise way?

Comment: @BobSwanson: The [TAP pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx) states that tasks are returned "hot" - that is,, `PairTaskAsync` starts when you call it. You can put a stopwatch inside `PairTaskAsync` to measure both A and B. I have a [book that covers both asynchrony and parallelism](http://stephencleary.com/book/).